# Collection generating the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of the collection of compact sets (Castaing-Valadier).

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

I'm working on an article "Castaing-Valadier" and in Chapter 2 there is this theorem:

> If $X$ is a separable metric space, the Borel $\sigma$-field on $\mathcal{P}_K(X)$ (the collection of compact subsets of $X$ with the Hausdorff topology) is generated by the sets $\lbrace K; K\subset U \rbrace$  ($U$ open)
>   and is also generated by the sets $\{K; K \cap V \neq \emptyset \}$ ($V$ open).

At the beginning of the proof it is said: "Remark that $V=\displaystyle\bigcup_{n} F_n$ with $F_n=\lbrace x; d(x,X\setminus V)\geq \frac1n \rbrace$ ". I don't understad this remark!
I need help please.

Comment: I dont understand why :$V=\displaystyle\bigcup_{n} F_n$ with $F_n=\lbrace x; d(x,X\setminus V)\geq \frac1n \rbrace$ ?

Answer (score 1):

First show the following: if $F$ is closed, then the following statement are equivalent:

1. $x$ is an element of $F$;
2. $d(x,F)=0$.

   - If $x\in F_n$ for some $n$, then $d(x,X\setminus V)\geqslant \frac 1n>0$. In particular, as $X\setminus V$ is closed, $x\notin X\setminus V$ so $x\in V$.
   - Conversely, if $x\in V$ then $d(x,X\setminus V)>0$ so $x\in F_n$ for any $n$ such that $\frac 1n\leqslant d(x,X\setminus V)$.

Comment: Please , after that they say :$\lbrace K;K\cap (\bigcup F_n)\rbrace=\lbrace K,K\cap (\displaystyle \cup_{n} F_n)\neq0 \rbrace= \bigcup[\mathcal{P}_K(X)-{K, K\subset X-F_n}]$ i dont understand the last equality